# Certbot - SSL: unknown protocol error

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, lets-encrypt

We are trying to install and use Certbot. We have installed it and we tried to install one certificate (for `https://www.tuxx.cn/`), but this gives the following error when using Mozilla Firefox:
`SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`

Using Curl, we also get an error (but a different one):
`curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol`

This is our Apache configuration:

```
irtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.tuxx.cn
  DocumentRoot /var/www/current/httpdocs

    SSLEngine on

    # Intermediate configuration, tweak to your needs
    SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES12$
    SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
    SSLCompression          off

    SSLOptions +StrictRequire

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.tuxx.cn/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.tuxx.cn/privkey.pem
 <Directory "/var/www/current/httpdocs">
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What are we doing wrong here?

P.S. We tried to find out what the difference was between the default certbot Apache configuration and our Apache configuration. It turned out that we had to split our configuration into subconfigurations per domain in order for certbot to detect the configuration files.

Comment: Please confirm that your copy-and-paste is correct as your final cipher: `DHE-DSS-A$` doesn't appear to be a valid one. If that is your actual config, that might be the cause of your error messages though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It was indeed not correct, but now it should be correct.